# javafx How markdown realizes what you see is what you get?

Tags: markdown

I want to implement a WYSIWYG editor similar to marktext using javafx, but what confuses me is how to implement WYSIWYG in the same text area?

Answer (score 1):

There is for instance [FXMisc/RichTextFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX) with miscellaneous demos.
I think that is easier than a WebView and doing HTML in the background.

This allows you to style text parts.

***Edit and result view:*** Markdown is normally edited in a left pane in plain text, and displayed in a right pane in styled text.

***Pure WYSIWYG without markdown commands:*** A pure WYSIWYG editing is possible with stateful controls (a combobox for `#`, `##`, `###`, and so on).

***Commands mixed with WYSIWYG:*** *(Wich I think you are asking for: "one text area".)* To display it in one text area is hence not perfect. You could render the style commands like `#` (title line) in grey / special font / with rounded border, and the rest of the line in (title) style.

Even tables with `----` can be layouted intelligently to dynamically fixed column widths. That could become tricky.

1. The markdown comamnds you want to support, examples.
2. Code text: *bold text part:*

   `**bold text**`
3. Representation in some md viewer

   **bold text**
4. Your selected representation (in the text area)

   `[**[`**bold text**`]**]`
5. Tooltips & context menues.
6. Menu command to blend out the mark-down commands: really WYSIWYG.